# ERROR: Expected 'Id' column to be of type 'Int32', but was 'String'

Tags: python, export-to-csv, kaggle

I am trying to upload the CSV for a KAGGLE Problem: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/overview

But when I do that I get the above error. I typecasted my Id columns to int32 but still, it gives me the problem. I also tried float64. I don't have any scientific values in my Id column.

What do I do?
Command Used to Write:

```
Final_DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(Result,columns = ['Id','SalePrice'])

FinalDataFrame.tocsv("D:/Study Material/Py_Programs/Kaggle/House Prices Advanced Regression Techniques/Prediction.csv",index = False)

Sample Output :

[[ 1463. 201899.30306688]

[ 1464. 196082.34616396]

[ 1465. 219045.36294988]]
```

It's like in CSV saved file it automatically gets converted to a string. I don't know I didn't get this problem while solving the Titanic problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: CSV is an innately textual format. Anything in a CSV file is written as text, and has to be converted back out after being read. Anyhow -- ensure that you're giving us a [mre], code that's complete enough to reproduce the problem with no additions or changes needed (but also the *shortest possible thing* that's complete as described above).

Comment: all data in all CSV files are only string - program or user has to decide which data convert to number. Using module `csv` you have to convert manually, using `pandas` it can convert if it recognize numbers in column.

Comment: your output doesn't look like data in CSV file - rather like numpy array displayed on screen.

Comment: I need to upload this CSV prediction file in KAGGLE but the kaggle interface shows above Error.    @furas its just output of screen as to how my data looks like the first column is ID and second one is predicted output.

Comment: is this full error message ? Is Kaggle expect CSV file ? Maybe it expect something different. Maybe in column ID you have data which can't be converted to integer and Kaggle shows you this as error - you have to open CVS file to see if all values are numbers which can be converted to iteger.  Dot in you output can makes problem.

Comment: BTW: there is `sample_submition.csv` so you can open it and your file in text editor and compare if they look similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a dictionary, where the index column has been generatend using `range()`:

```
keys = range(1461, 1461 + len(predictions))
df_subm = pd.DataFrame({'Id': keys, 'SalePrice': predictions})
df_subm.to_csv('test_results.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the id to int32 in the results loading section, the problem is solved.

```
submission_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Here: `submission_df['Id'] = test_df["Id"].astype("Int32")`

Answer (score -1):

Before conversion:

```
data.dtypes
Id           float64
SalePrice    float64
dtype: object
```

After conversion:

```
data["Id"] = data["Id"].astype(int)
Id             int32
SalePrice    float64
dtype: object
```

It will work